# Obj-C, Storekit restoreCompletedTransactions returns zero transactions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storekit

I'm having some problems restoring completed transactions.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

I've added the observer mentioned in several examples, I've tried adding `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` and already have `updatedTransactions`. `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` says I have zero transactions.

I can buy a product and if I try to buy again, it stops me and says I've already bought the product, using this code.

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

I thought maybe I had a problem with my bundle identifier, but that seems fine and the buy wouldn't work if it wasn't.

I have been trying this on the device as well as the simulator, but this has the same result. Also, it doesn't make a difference If I'm using UK or US store.

I'm really grasping at straws to find out why this doesn't work for me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to do it like this and check the array count is it return zero also ?

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems
{
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}//You Call This Function

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
  purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
  {
      NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
      [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I check that, that's what gives me zero

Comment: are you implement `restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError` method ?

Comment: Yes but I get `received restored transactions: 0`

Comment: There was a problem with the sandbox store last week

Comment: Note that you don't have to populate an `NSMutableDictionary` in a `for` loop. You can just do `purchasedItemIDs = [queue.transactions valueForKeyPath:@"payment.productIdentifier"]`

Comment: received restored transactions: 0 

Why is this so difficult ... WHAT IS THE SOLUTION?!?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When you create a new product to be sold in your store, you choose whether that product can be restored or not.

So the question is, is your product configured to allow restores?

Comment: thanks, but I can't see that anywhere, it's a none consumable product ??

Comment: I think none-consumable implies you can, so yes.